# Migrate data to remote Cosmos Document DB emulator

Tags: networking, azure-cosmosdb, data-migration

I am using the DocumentDB Migration tool to move some json from my local dev machine to a Remote DocumentDB emulator running on another machine on my local network. When I run the DT.exe migration, it throws this error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

From the error I understand it is a certificate problem but I have no idea how to solve it. I am running the emulator with /AllowNetworkAccess on port=443 and using the default Emulator Key (https://myservername). I then use the following ConnectionString in DT.exe:

```
AccountEndpoint=https://myservername/;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==;Database=MyDBName
```

Has anybody tried doing this before?

Comment: I have a similar problem connecting with a local c# client to a remote emulator. The error message is the same. I assume that the emulator uses a ssl certificate issued to localhost, which is not valid on any other host. If it was possible to switch of ssl validation, it might work.

Comment: I got round it by exporting the certificate on the remote machine (where the emulator is running) and then importing it on my dev machine. I do not have much knowledge on how it all works and I will do some more research and reading about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this error and I've been able to fix it the following way. I'm just gonna write exactly what I did. I'm not sure whether creating certificates was part of solving this problem.

**Generate certificates**

First of all I went to the root folder of Azure Cosmos DB Emulator `C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator` and opened the CMD here. Then I ran the command `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /GenCert=127.0.0.1,localhost`.

**Remove Cosmos DB Emulator**

After creating the certificates, I removed the Emulator. First of all, stop the Emulator in the system tray. After that, go to `Control Panel -> Uninstall a program`. Click on `Azure Cosmos DB Emulator` and click `Uninstall`. Follow the prompt and Cosmos DB should be uninstalled.

**Remove remaining files manually**

Some files may still be left. It's best to delete these by hand. Go to `C:\Program Files\` in the File Explorer and remove the `Azure Cosmos DB Emulator` folder. If it says it's in use, it might be because you still have the Command Prompt open. Close this and you should be good to go.

Some other files might still be in the `%LOCALAPPDATA%`. In that folder remove the `CosmosDBEmulator` folder.

**Install Cosmos DB**

After removing all the files I installed Cosmos DB again, and it magically worked.

I still don't know if this is actually a good fix, but it fixed it for me. So I hope it might help someone else in the future.